# Invalid login attempt in seed MVC5 Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I use MVC5. Entity Framework 6 code first approach

I renamed `ApplicationUser` to `User` according to [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5izES2OQ2k)

When I create a user in seed method as below, everything in database looks good and password look encrypted. But I get  `Invalid login attempt` when I try to login to my system, If I create another user directly It works and login without any problems
The password is well encrypted and there is no errors after running `Update-Database` in PM console

```
    string ADMIN_EMAIL= "xxxxxx@xxxx.xxx";
    string PASSWORD = "xxxxxx";
        if (!context.Users.Any())
        {
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

            var userStore = new UserStore<User>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore);

            // Add User
            var currentUser = userManager.FindByEmail(ADMIN_EMAIL);
            if (currentUser == null)
            {
                currentUser = new User()
                {
                    Email = ADMIN_EMAIL,
                    PhoneNumber = "0123456789",
                    UserName = "abdallah",
                    LockoutEnabled = true,
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D")
                };
                IdentityResult result = userManager.Create(currentUser, PASSWORD);
                if (result.Succeeded == false)
                {
                    throw new Exception(result.Errors.First());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where is your Login action method code?

Comment: I didn't change any thing

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer

I got `Invalid login attempt` because the field `UserName` is not equal to `Email` field. I just make `UserName` value = `Email`

```
            currentUser = new User()
            {
                Email = ADMIN_EMAIL,
                UserName = ADMIN_EMAIL,
                PhoneNumber = "0123456789",
                LockoutEnabled = true,
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D")
            };
```

I don't know how to change user name to be a readable name, If anybody know how to change them please make a comment here

Answer (score 4):

I added a **UserName** Field in the **RegisterViewModel** and **RegisterView**. That way a user can enter his Name. Then in the **Register** function in the **AccountController**, I changed *UserName = model.Email* to *UserName = model.UserName*.

It seemed to work for awhile as I was getting UserName on the Menu and I was successfully logged in. But, when I logged out, I wasn't able to log back in. I tried many things but nothing seemed to be working.

After a little while, I discovered the problem that was in the **Login** function in the **AccountController**. The problem was here :

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

Although, it is sending the **Email** to the **PasswordSignInAsync**, it's not the required value. The **PasswordSignInAsync** is expecting a **UserName**, so it's not working with this Email because we changed the UserName.

Luckily, there was another override of this function available which requires **ApplicationUser user** instread of **string UserName**. So, I did the following and it's working again:

```
var user = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Email == model.Email).First();
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: this is moronic the way Microsoft set this code. What if I want to allow the same UserNames such as Mike C and another Mike C, etc. I want only the emails to be unique. So in the PasswordSignInAsync(), they should be passing in the user's "id" which will always be unique since it is a GUID instead of email or username.

Comment: also, it is not an override in your last step. Whatever you pass in (email, username, etc.) will be the value used to try and find a matching UserName in the database. So even the default setting:  PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email ...) is truly bazaar in that it lets you think email is what is being used to find the row to check the password hash. It is simply passing in the email, and then trying to find a match on Username that matches the email. Really bad nomenclature and really bad design.

Comment: BTW, this  is nothing bad on you Aadam, I just happen to be venting here against Microsoft because I just realized what is going on with this confusing setup.

Comment: yeah, this frustrated me a lot back then. don't know if they updated the API design after that. Hope that they did.